# biology models which uses a system of differential equations

Tags: mathematical-modeling, biology

I am trying to find mathematical models used in Biology that uses a system of differential equations.

I found the lotka-volterra model and Michaelis-Menten kinetics but I would like to know more than just this two.

Can anyone give a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: The [SIR model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model) might fit what you are looking for.

Comment: If you're looking for a reference of more complex and applicable models, try the book "Introduction to Mathematical Oncology" by Yang Kuang.

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, it can be hard to find mathematical modelling in biology that is [*not* differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248461/is-there-any-research-in-mathematical-biology-that-isnt-heavy-in-differential-e?rq=1). But here are some examples.

- The [Hodgkin-Huxley model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodgkin%E2%80%93Huxley_model) (or other [biological neuron models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_neuron_model)) of the cellular dynamics of neurons. The [Hindmarsh-Rose model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindmarsh%E2%80%93Rose_model) is another simple model that exhibits bursting.
- Mathematical models of oncological tumor growth (e.g. [[1]](https://tbiomed.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12976-016-0032-7) or [[2]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00285-003-0211-0)).
- Among predator-prey models, [there are quite a few DE models](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Predator-prey_model) beyond Lotka-Volterra. You can also extend to spatial distributions using PDEs (e.g. [[1]](https://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Cl8e4-4oWBwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=differential+equation+ecology&ots=KVgRdM3XcY&sig=8B-imhyL-0xH_MVIQf9m8dqXDDc#v=onepage&q=differential%20equation%20ecology&f=false) or [[2]](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2307/1939378)). [Fisher's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_equation) is a related model of gene propagation.
- Turing's model of developmental morphogenesis (e.g. [[1]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3363041/) or [[2]](http://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf)).
- In pharmacology, you can model ADME kinetics via DEs called PBPK models (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiologically_based_pharmacokinetic_modelling))
- The [rate equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_equation) play a large role in biochemistry. Of course, this is related to the [Michaelis-Menten equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics).
- The spreading of the electrophysiological cardiac contraction  signal is modelled either by a reaction-diffusion or an eikonal equation (e.g. [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.108106#fulltext)).
- The [replicator equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation) is a common DE in evolutionary game theory.
- Non-linear differential equations are good models for cellular dynamics, incorporating gene expression, translation, the cell cycle, etc... (e.g. [[1]](http://arep.med.harvard.edu/pdf/Chen99.pdf), [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_model)).
- There are large-scale models of neural activity (i.e. modelling neural populations rather than single neurons) that utilize differential equations 
  (e.g. [[1]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811915000051), [[2]](http://www.ccnss.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Breaks_17_NatNeuro.pdf)). See also [neural mass model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_oscillation#Neural_mass_model).
- In the field of animal behaviour, often stochastic differential equations are used (though that is true for many of the other ones mentioned above too). You can, however, look at collective flocking behaviours (e.g. the [Cucker-Smale model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04887.pdf)) and compartmental models of behaviour (described via DEs).

Also pretty much everything in biophysics is described by differential equations (e.g. models of protein folding, molecular dynamics, continuum mechanical modelling of tissue, etc...).